# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setUserName(value)
  }
```

This is my handleChange function, first time writing typescript in react.  I want to know why I get the following in vs code:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement'.ts(2339)
```

Everything works fine, however this won't go away.

Edit:  First of all, thank you for sharing that cheatsheet! Sure to be a big help!

Here is the file in it's entirety:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setUserName(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          value={userName}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried to remove the handle change and out the function directly in the onChange prop, however the problem persists.

Could it be a problem with my tsconfig.json?  I'm just using the default config from CRA

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Friend of the React and TypeScript communities here...

Based on the information you've provided, it's hard to tell why TypeScript might be complaining. I've put together a CodeSandbox to demonstrate that I am **not** seeing the same error.

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/jsjoeio/react-ts-with-input/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx&theme=dark)

**UPDATED**

Thanks for adding the file for more context. Everything looks fine, including your `tsconfig.json`. Do you have the `@types` packages for React installed i.e.

```
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
```

That's the only other thing that comes to mind. If that doesn't fix it, can you include a link to a repo or CodeSandbox with the error reproduced? Then I can take a closer look.

> first time writing typescript in react

I recommend checking out the [`react-typescript-cheatsheet`](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet) if you haven't already. It's a fantastic reference when you're new to writing TypeScript in React.

Comment: Hey Joe, I edited my original post to include more code.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: Hey Taylor, thanks for doing that! I went ahead and updated my answer. Let's hope that gets us closer!

Comment: Hey Joe, so I think I've narrowed it down to being a vs code setting.  I recreated the situation on my work machine, and there is no problem at all!  So I'm now trying to figure out what the vs code setting could be...

Comment: setting "typescript.validate.enable": false removed the issue.  However, I don't know if thats a great fix.

Comment: Hmm..That's very strange. If you want to export your settings and share it in a gist, I'd be happy to help you look.

For TS projects, I typically follow this guide to get ESLint, Prettier, VSCode and TypeScript to play nicely. Maybe it could help: https://dev.to/robertcoopercode/using-eslint-and-prettier-in-a-typescript-project-53jb